# How is asking where to find the Objective-C language reference "too localized"?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/q/14347440/581994

Given that about half the traffic on SO is asking about Objective-C related issues, how could asking to find the "mother" reference possibly be "only relevant to a small geographic area", et al??

Comment: "Given that about half the traffic on SO is asking about Objective-C related issues" you should check your math.

Comment: "Too localized" seems like the wrong close reason. Perhaps "Not Constructive" would be better?

Comment: @DanielFischer - I did, just a couple of minutes ago.  About half the threads were iOS/Objective-C related.

Comment: @TheDarkAvenger That's because the homepage is biased towards your tags. If you look at the recent tags column, C# and Java are at 68 and 66, whereas Objective-C is at a measly 12.

Comment: Hmm, the top 8 tags are C#, Java, PHP, JavaScript, Android, JQuery, C++ and iPhone. Only the last looks really iOS/Objective-C related.

Comment: @Mysticial - I just counted the stuff on the first page.  49 of 90 threads were tagged Objective-C or iOS or iPhone or OSx.  I think that's sufficient to count as "about half"

Comment: @TheDarkAvenger Like I said, the homepage is biased heavily towards your tags. For example, more than half the stuff on my homepage is C++ and Java - and not a single C# or Objective-C question.

Comment: The first page is programmed to show you stuff that you might be interested in based on your favorite tags and tags you frequently ask/answer questions in.  It's not a good gauge of popularity.

Comment: @TheDarkAvenger On http://stackoverflow.com/questions I counted just now two threads (out of 50) with unambiguous connection to Objective-C, and four if I also count the two with only `xcode` as "related" tags.

Comment: @DanielFischer I assume that's for the "new" or "active" tabs. The "votes" tab is all Git and Javascript with a bit Python and C++... lol

Comment: @Mysticial "New" it was.

Answer (score 9):

I generally choose "Too Localized" as a proxy for [General Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043), when the answer to the question is "Look in the manual, or do a Google Search."  I admit that this choice is not without controversy.

Too Localized is especially apt for the question you linked, since a Google Search only turns up older versions of the book you requested.  Consequently, it fits into [Joel's archetypal example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87415/102937) of:

```
Why is there a green Honda Civic parked out in front of my house?

Is it still there?

Now is it there?
```

As you can see, choosing a close reason for questions that are the "perfect storm" (i.e. they meet several possible criteria for closing) can be difficult, as people will often argue about the veracity of the close reason instead of the more pressing issue, which is that the question really doesn't belong on the site anyway.

Comment: Any links to Apple's documentation on Stack Overflow are problematic, because Apple likes to keep changing their documentation URL schemes. This is why searches for this particular document dead-end on Google right now, because Apple has moved this from where it used to be a little while ago. Therefore, any answer to a question like this would go out of date the next time that Apple moved this stuff again. "Too localized" might indeed apply here, since time is a factor in the answers to a question like this.

Answer (score 7):

From the "Too Localized" message:

> it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a *specific moment in time*, or an extraordinarily narrow situation...

Emphasis added.

Any answer would only apply for right now. It might not apply for next week. Or next year. Or five years from now, when linked references die.

The reason this does not apply to general technology questions is that the questions tend to presume or outright indicate a specific version. If I ask a question about jQuery 1.4, correct answers to that question will *always* be correct for jQuery 1.4 - no matter what version is the current one out.

For the record, "Not Constructive" and "Off-Topic" would also be appropriate reasons to close that question.

Comment: IMO that's not a very good reason. You could close any technology-specific question with the same rationale.

Comment: @PeterOlson - Right.  There are thousands of questions that are only relevant to a particular release/version of something.

Comment: @PeterOlson Not really. A question about jQuery 1.4, for example, will *always* be relevant to jQuery 1.4 - regardless whether 2.0 is on the horizon.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - iOS version-related questions become irrelevant fairly quickly, since Apple effectively drops support for older versions then they're about two revs back.  The language itself is probably more stable.

Comment: @TheDarkAvenger That's one reason why I prefer "Off-Topic" or "Not Constructive" for that kind of question.

Comment: @TheDarkAvenger - I'm not sure that answers to iOS questions go out of date as frequently as you think, as I argued here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139048/evolving-subject-qas-are-outdated/139064#139064